# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im having a problem with running my rails server. ive set the abstract_mysql2_adapters at initializer that consist of:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
end
```

and it solved my rake db:migrate problem, but when i try to run my rails server it gives me this error.

> C:/Users/XXXX/Documents/RoRCmS/simple_cms/config/initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter.rb:2:in `<class:Mysql2Adapter>': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAda
>   pters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES (NameError)
>           from C:/Users/John/Documents/RoRCmS/simple_cms/config/initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter.rb:1:in`'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:609:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in`each'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:608:in `block in <class:Engine>'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in`block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in`block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`call'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in`tsort_each'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
>           from C:/Users/John/Documents/RoRCmS/simple_cms/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
>           from C:/Users/John/Documents/RoRCmS/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in`require'
>           from C:/Users/John/Documents/RoRCmS/simple_cms/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`instance_eval'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>           from C:/Users/John/Documents/RoRCmS/simple_cms/config.ru:in`new'
>           from C:/Users/John/Documents/RoRCmS/simple_cms/config.ru:in `<main>'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`eval'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`parse_file'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in`app'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.5.5/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in`wrapped_app'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:78:in`block in '
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
>           from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in`'
>           from bin/rails:4:in `require'
>           from bin/rails:4:in`'

I really need to solve this problem now.. thanks guys.

Answer (score 6):

I solved it as follows. After importing a legacy sql dumpfile into MySQL with `mysql -u username -p database_name < file.sql`, I proceeded to perform a migration with `bin/rake db:migrate`, but I encountered the error `Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL; if you need NULL in a key, use UNIQUE instead`.

So I tried the same monkey patch as you, as suggested by user pjg here https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13247#issuecomment-32425844, but then I encountered your error

```
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter::NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES (NameError)
```

I followed user John Geliberte's advice and updated my Gemfile with `gem 'activerecord-native_db_types_override'` and checked that I also had `gem 'mysql2'` (NOT 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' which causes other errors) and ran `bundle install`.

I used the the documentation associated with the [activerecord-native_db_types_override gem](https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-native_db_types_override) and applied property for NATIVE_DATABASE_TYPES mentioned in [Rails ActiveRecord library file](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_mysql_adapter.rb) for abstract_mysql_adapter, such that I made the following changes:

I created **config/initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter.rb** and added:

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter'
NativeDbTypesOverride.configure({
  ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter => {
    primary_key: "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
  }
})
```

I created **config/environment.rb** and add the following to load the monkey patch:

```
require File.expand_path('../initializers/abstract_mysql2_adapter.rb', __FILE__)
```

I checked that **config/database.yml** contained 'adapter: mysql2' for the db connection I wanted to use.

I then ran `bin/rake db:migrate` and it successfully performed the migration.

I have made a [pull request](https://github.com/garysweaver/activerecord-native_db_types_override/pull/1) to the documentation for the ActiveRecord Native Database Types Override Gem.

It was much easier to downgrade from MySQL 5.7 to 5.5 instead though.

My system:

- `mysql -V` is `mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.13`
- `rails -v` is `4.2.4`
- `ruby -v` is `ruby 2.3.0p0`

Answer (score 5):

SOLVED: i added the gem : gem 'activerecord-native_db_types_override'

Answer (score -1):

Try this code instead:

```
class ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::Mysql2Adapter
  def modify_types(types)
    super
    types[:primary_key] = "int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY"
    types
  end
end
```

Comment: it solves my rails server command issue but It gives this error: Mysql2::Error: All parts of a PRIMARY KEY must be NOT NULL

Comment: What if you add NOT NULL to primary key definition

Comment: ive tried int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL but still gives me the same error